# Applying built-in and custom created functions on dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data of sales that have different columns. Data is in Pandas DataFrame type. Apply a custom function on my data and combine all data by same categories. Unfortunately I can not post dataset here but I have sample data like following:

```
     item  value
0   Item A  59
1   Item B  95
2   Item B  82
3   Item C  40
4   Item A  11
```

Now what I want is to create a function and apply that function on data. Here is my code

```
sum_all = {}
def verify(items , col):
    for i,v in items,col:
        if i == 'item A':
            sum_all[i] += v
            # and so on
            # At the end of this function
    return sum_all
```

I want to functions on my data one will be built-in sum function and the second is verify at the same time. and results will look like following:

```
item    sum   verify

Item A   70     70
Item B   177    177
Item C   40     40
```

Considering that this is not my real data this is dummy data much similar to mine. I also searched it on stack overflow and I found few good solutions but they did not work exactly I wanted. I also commented on those post but didn't get a reply yet. I will be thankful if you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about groupby and agg function. As this is the best of my knowledge, you can try this code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Item A',59],['Item B',95],['Item B',82],['Item C',40],['Item A',11]], columns=['item','value'])

# If using Python3
from functools import reduce

def verify(series):
       return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, series)

df.groupby('item').agg({'value': ['sum', verify]})
```

Comment: This is working well. But I will wait for some time to explore other's solutions. Thanks